# Read Chinese characters from Excel worksheet? (Always returns "????")

Tags: excel, vba, non-ascii-characters

How do I read Chinese characters from Excel cells and write them to a file? When I take values by

```
Worksheets(ActiveCell.Worksheet.Name).Cells(3, columnNumbers(0)).value
```

it always returns "????????"

Comment: See if this helps? http://www.ureader.com/msg/11051084.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim fileStream, FilePath As String    

'Full properties file path
propFilePath = "C:\file.properties"

'Create Stream object
Set fileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

'Specify stream type – we want To save text/string data.
fileStream.Type = 2

'Specify charset For the source text data.
fileStream.Charset = "utf-8"

'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
fileStream.Open
fileStream.writetext "write something here"

'Save binary data To disk
fileStream.SaveToFile FilePath, 2
fileStream.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

1. this may be csv file
2. open with text editor, save in the UTF8 or UNICODE format